# Can i create an app with react similar to angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been thinking of creating an hybrid app. I worked with ionic before, but i don't have any clue about react.
      What i exactly needed is 'code once run anywhere' approach. The angular 2 is doing great in that i can write code for web app, android , apple devices and even windows.
I want to know whether i can do this in React. Can I create an app with react which runs on both web and mobile app as platform independent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 and React are great frameworks/library(for react) which can run almost anywhere. In fact lets first determine what we mean with anywhere.

Angular 2 can server that app on web and if you are using a responsive format can serve mobile devices as well really fast. On devices you can serve it with ionic but the catch here is that this will be served with webviews which is actually a small placement inside the app to show html content. This rendering is rubbish if you want to serve native experience to the user. If not, then great ! Also you can have windows phones as well.

React on the other hand is easy to go in to code fast. I recommend using redux (which might take a while to get used to). Also with responsive design can serve many web devices really fast. Now on the smartphones the experience is native. Yes exactly native ! So if you plan the application correctly and split the logic right you can serve from the same app both application web + mobile. For windows phones now there is a limitation.

For desktops you can use electron as well and have it all!

I guess for me you must consider what your target is (time, devices, experience) and then decide.

Have fun!

Comment: I would personally recommend starting out without Redux since it has a steep learning curve if you are just starting out with react/react-native. Also if you really want to use Material design, it can be done relatively easy with a module, like https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit

Comment: I agree but if you start with react without state management like redux is hard to change afterwards. I recommend to print out the cycle graph of redux (action, reducer paradigm) and learn it on the way :D

Comment: I agree, state management should be learned very early on to reduce issues in the future. Just that the first thing to learn and understand need to be React so that if anything goes wrong in the React/Redux implementation, it is easy to understand where and why something breaks. :D I don't want to imagine the horrors of trying to implement Redux after a project is complete. :D but the main priority should be learning the core of React and then using that knowledge to understand the need for Redux.